# Calculation in group cohomology with nontrivial coefficients

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, homology-cohomology

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero. Let $V = \operatorname{Ind}_1^{\mathbb Z/2} \mathbf 1$ denote the regular representation of $\mathbb Z/2$ over $k$. Then $V \oplus V$ is a representation of $(\mathbb Z/2)^2$, where the $i$-th copy of $\mathbb Z/2$ acts nontrivially on the $i$-th copy of $V$. I would like to compute the first cohomology group $H^1((\mathbb Z/2)^2, V\oplus V)$. The only tool I could think of using was the inflation-restriction exact sequence.

Numbering the copies of $\mathbb Z/2$ and $V$ to keep track of actions, we have
$$H^1(\mathbb Z/2_2, (V_1 \oplus V_2)^{\mathbb Z/2_1}) = \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb {Z/2}_2, k) \oplus H^1(\mathbb Z/2_2, V) = \{\pm 1\} \oplus 0,$$ the last equality being due to Shapiro's lemma applied to the second summand.

We also have $$H^1(\mathbb Z/2_1, V \oplus V)^{\mathbb Z/2_2} = 0 \oplus \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb Z/2_1, V_2)^{\mathbb Z/2_2} = \{\pm 1\},$$

from which

$$1 \to \{\pm 1\} \to H^1((\mathbb Z/2)^2, V\oplus V) \to \{\pm 1\} \to H^2(\mathbb Z/2_2, (V_1 \oplus V_2)^{\mathbb Z/2_1}).$$

I don't know how to calculate this $H^2$, or the image of $\{\pm 1\}$ inside it coming from the transgression homomorphism. I suppose one might be able to calculate the group I'm interested in by hand, but I'd be particularly interested in general methods.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you very much for your comment. Would you mind elaborating a little on this statement?

Comment: For a different approach: there's a Künneth formula for group cohomology, so you can reduce this to the case of cyclic groups.